# Join multiple parallel object into a single List

Tags: java, concurrency, java-stream

I've a map of key-value and iterating over keys, and calling service and based on the response, I am adding all the response to some `uberList`

How can I execute the different operations concurrently? Will changing `stream()` to `parallelStream()` do the trick? Does it synchronize when it adds to `uberList`?

The idea is to minimize the response time.

```
List<MyClass> uberList = new LinkedList<>();

Map<String, List<MyOtherClass>> map = new HashMap();

//Populate map

map.entrySet().stream().filter(s -> s.getValue().size() > 0 && s.getValue().values().size() > 0).forEach(
   y  -> {

        // Do stuff
        if(noError) {
            uberList.add(MyClass3);
        }

   }

}  

//Do stuff on uberList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I execute the different operations concurrently?

One thread can do one task at a time. If you want to do multiple operations concurrently, you have to offwork to other threads.
You can either creating new Thread or using ExecutorService to manage thread pool, queue the task and execute task for you.

> Will changing stream() to parallelStream() do the trick?

Yes it does. Internally, `parallelStream()` use the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` to run tasks for you. But keep in mind that the `parallelStream()` has no guarantee about if the returned stream is paralleled (but for now, the current implementation return a paralleled one)

> Does it synchronize when it adds to uberList?

It's up to you to do the synchronization part in `forEach` pipeline. Normally you do not want to call `collection.add()` inside `forEach` to create collection. Instead you should use `.map().collect(toX())` methods. It frees you from synchronizatin part:

1. It does not required to know about your local variable (in this case `uberlist`. And it will not modify it on execution, help reduce a lot of strange bugs caused of concurrency
2. You can freely change the type of collection in `.collect()` part. It give you more control over the result type.
3. It does not require thread-safe or synchronization on given collection when using with parallel stream. Because "multiple intermediate results may be instantiated, populated, and merged so as to maintain isolation of mutable data structures" ([Read more about this here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-))

So what you want is to execute multiple similar service call at the same time and collect your result into a list.

You can do it simply by parallel stream:

```
uberList = map.entrySet().stream()
                         .parallel()  // Use .stream().parallel() to force parallism. The .parallelStream() does not guarantee that the returned stream is parallel stream
                         .filter(yourCondition)
                         .map(e -> yourService.methodCall(e))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Pretty cool, isn't it?

But as I stated, the default parallel stream use `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` for thread queueing and executing.

The bad part is if your `yourService.methodCall(e)` **do heavy IO stuff** (like HTTP call, even db call...) or **long running task** then it may exhaust the pool, other incoming tasks will queued forever to wait for execution.

So typically all other tasks depend on this common pool (not only your own `yourService.methodCall(e)`, but all other parallel stream) will be slow down due to queueing time.

To solve this problem, you can force execute parallelism on your own fork-join pool:

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(4); // Typically set it to Runtime.availableProcessors()
uberlist = forkJoinPool.submit(() -> {
     return map.entrySet().stream()
                             .parallel()  // Use .stream().parallel() to force parallism. The .parallelStream() does not guarantee that the returned stream is parallel stream
                             .filter(yourCondition)
                             .map(e -> yourService.methodCall(e))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}).get();
```

Comment: How does it help if yourService.methodCall(e) calls RestTemplate (Network) calls, and any of them could be taking more time and giving a exception?

Comment: Short answer: If you fear your methods hang forever, then set timeout for your `RestTemplate`. Long answer: Basically, thread pool only helps you to parallel the tasks, gives more throughput by execute multitasks simultaneously, speed up the whole process (but it cannot speed up individual task).  Any problem you face in single threaded task also happens in multiple threaded pool.

Comment: I was looking a timeout for the entire execution, more on the lines of `ExecutorService.awaitTermination` , and not handling the entire JVM if the end system where the network call is made goes down.

Comment: 1. You should not manually terminate your pool. As your pool will be reused for every request. Creating a threadpool is an intensive operation. 2. Waiting for entire execution is bad. Do you wait 10 minutes to realize that one of your downloads is fail? You always want to `fail fast`, return the thread to the pool for later execution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use `parallelStream` for concurrency, only for parallelism. (That is: use it for tasks where you want to use multiple physical processes efficiently on a task that's conceptually sequential, not for tasks where you want multiple things going on at the same time conceptually.)

In your case you would probably be better off using an `ExecutorService`, or more specifically `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableExecutorService` from Google Guava (warning: I haven't tried to compile the below code, there may be syntax errors):

```
int MAX_NUMBER_OF_SIMULTANEOUS_REQUESTS = 100;
ListeningExecutorService myExecutor = 
    MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_NUMBER_OF_SIMULTANEOUS_REQUESTS));

List<ListenableFuture<Optional<MyClass>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<MyOtherClass>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getValue().size() > 0 && entry.getValue().values().size() > 0) {
    futures.add(myExecutor.submit(() -> {    
      // Do stuff
      if(noError) {
        return Optional.of(MyClass3);
      } else {
        return Optional.empty();
      }
    }));
  }
}

List<MyClass> uberList = Futures.successfulAsList(futures)
    .get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES /* adjust as necessary */)
    .stream()
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The advantage of this code is that it allows you to explicitly specify that the tasks should all start at the "same time" (at least conceptually) and allows you to control your concurrency explicitly (how many simultaneous requests are allowed? What do we do if some of the tasks fail? How long are we willing to wait? etc). Parallel streams aren't really for that.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing is i dont use guava. So do we have native support?

Comment: Yes you can use a plain ExecutorService as well, you just won't get nice conveniences like `Futures.successfulAsList`. Instead you can just iterate over the list of futures after you've constructed it and call `get` on each one.

Comment: `.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES /* adjust as necessary */)` is pretty scary. Either the value is too large or too small with the real execution time. You should use `join()` instead

Comment: I don't follow. If the potential of waiting some particular cutoff is scary, then surely the prospect of waiting an unbounded amount of time is even scarier?

Comment: Read my answer below

Comment: I don't understand. Your code doesn't do anything to address the "scary" timeout concern and in fact makes it worse  -- if any I/O call hangs, your program will hang. AFAICT there's no mechanism for controlling how long you're willing to wait with a parallel stream, which is one of the reasons I said that it's not appropriate for concurrent jobs such as the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel Stream will help in execution concurrently. But it is not recommended to do forEach loop and add element in outside list. If you do that, you have to make  sure of synchnising external list. Better way of doing it is to use map and collect result into list. In this case, parallelStream takes care of synchronisation.

```
List<MyClass> uberList = map.entrySet().parallelStream().filter(s -> 
s.getValue().size() > 0 && s.getValue().values().size() > 
0).map(
y  -> {
    // Do stuff
        return MyClass3;
    }
 }
.filter(t -> check no ertor condition)
.collect (Collectors.toList())
```